# WSO2 Identity Server usernames with discriminator

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

A recent trend in applications is that users register with a username, even if it's not "unique" by also using a discriminator value: `Limnic#4391` for example.

Popular services such as Discord, Rocket League, Battle.net, ... use this. I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve this type of username system in WSO2. All I can find out of the box is to use emails.

To log in to these services, you do indeed use an email, but your shown username is the name with the discriminator. Could this be just email authentication and then claims which contain the discriminator and username?

Answer (score 1):

OOB WSO2 IS does not support this kind a feature, however you can write a customisation to add discrimination value to the username. However, usernames should be unique in the system. So you have to save the username value as it is with the discrimination value. And whenever you get the username value, you have to remove the discrimination value depends on your need.

As you mentioned, other option is to use a different claim to store the user name and discrimination value separately and authenticate using another unique value. (Such as email)